# MobileServiceClient LoginAsync succesfull, but each subsequent call fails

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Azure Mobile Service Client on Xamarin forms. Login using .LoginAsync("custom", user) seems succesfull, because a token and userid is returned to my client. However, the next call (ReadAsync on a MobileServiceTable) will fail (internal server error).

Using Fiddler, it seems that the mobile service client switches from contenttype application/json to html/text for no apparent reason.

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

The top row is the login, and the second row is a failed attempt to get data.

Then, for testing purposes, I set the App Service Authentication to Off on the Azure portal, and removed all the [Authorize] attributes.

Then, using the same client (without logging in obviously), I try the same ReadAsync method, and it's OK. The data is returned to the client.

Here's a second Fiddler screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in this second screenshot, contenttype = application/json.

I also tried login with Google instead of the custom login: everything OK.

So what's going on? Only when using custom login, the contenttype switches to html/text, and I get an 'internal server error'.

Here's the server-side custom authentication code:

```
    [Route(".auth/login/custom")]
public class CustomAuthController : ApiController
{
    private DataContext db;
    private string signingKey, audience, issuer;

    public CustomAuthController()
    {
        db = new DataContext();
        signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
        var website = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME");
        audience = $"https://{website}/";
        issuer = $"https://{website}/";
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] tblUser body)
    {
        if (body == null || body.Username == null || body.Password == null ||
            body.Username.Length == 0 || body.Password.Length == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest(); ;
        }

        if (!IsValidUser(body))
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        var claims = new Claim[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, body.Username)
        };

        JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
            claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
        return Ok(new LoginResult()
        {
            AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
            User = new LoginResultUser { UserId = body.Username }
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool IsValidUser(tblUser user)
    {
        return db.tblUsers.Count(u => u.Username.Equals(user.Username) && u.Password.Equals(user.Password)) > 0;
    }
}

public class LoginResult
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "authenticationToken")]
    public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
    public LoginResultUser User { get; set; }
}

public class LoginResultUser
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Client-side login in the shared code:

```
                MobileServiceUser mobileServiceUser = await client.LoginAsync("custom", JObject.FromObject(user));
```

As said before, a MobileServiceUser is returned with a token. Each subsequent call uses the token, but fails. The problem appears to be, that the contenttype is switched to html/text instead of application/json.

I have spent a few days now trying to figure this out, but to no avail. What am I missing here? 
Or is there a workaround of some sort, for example to force the IMobileServiceTable.ReadAsync() to use the correct content-type?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which document you refer to,is this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting and re-creating the Azure app. I did read somewhere on the internet (not able to find it again) that, to use custom authentication, you have to have a clean configuration. Clean meaning: if you had a Google+ authentication configured in th Azure portal beforehand, it won't work if you delete it, and then continue with the same app and use custom authentication.